# $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ from open set to open set

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, lipschitz-functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ be defined as $f((s,t))=2s$. Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ be an open set. Does this function map $A$ to an open set? Give a counterexample if false or proof if true.

I think this is true. My proof:

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Since $A$ is open, for every $\vec{a}\in A$, $\exists \delta > 0$ such that $B(\vec{a}, \delta)\subseteq A$, where $B(\vec{a}, \delta)=\{\vec{x}\in \mathbb{R}^2: \|\vec{x}-\vec{a}\|<\delta\}$. Since $f$ is Lipshitz with constant $c=2$, that is $|f((s,t))-f((s',t'))|= 2|s-s'|\le 2\sqrt{(s-s')^2+(t-t')^2}=2\|(s,t)-(s',t')\|=2\|\vec{x}-\vec{a}\|$, $f$ is continuous on $A$, so that $2|s-s'|<\varepsilon\iff |s-s'|<\frac\varepsilon2$. Thus, $f(B(\vec{a},\delta))=\{s\in \mathbb{R}:|s-s'|<\varepsilon/2\}=B(s',\epsilon /2)$, which is an open ball in the image of $A$ under $f$. Hence, $f(A)$ is open.

> Do you think this approach might be at least approximately correct?

Now, I also think there's probably a simpler approach: Simple $f$ is Lipschitz, it is continuous, so that, for every $\varepsilon >0$, $\exists \delta > 0$ such that $f(B(\vec{a}, \delta))\subseteq B(f(\vec{a}),\varepsilon)=B(2s', \varepsilon)$. But here the ball is centred at $2s'$ instead of $s'$, and it is of a different radius.

Would appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Did you use only Lipchitz property in your second argument?

Comment: Note  that Lipschitz continuity does not play any role here, You only need to obtain the  $f (B(a, \delta))$ with $a=(s',t')$ which is $(2s' +2\delta, 2s'  -2\delta, )$.  If you only used lipschitz property then your proof is wrong since the constant function $f=0$ is lipschitz but not open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint : $f(x,y) =x$ maps open square to open interval. DONE.

P.S any open set in $R^2$ can be written as Union (Possibly infinite) of open squares!

Comment: Thanks. But do you think my proof might be correct as well?

Comment: @sequence If you want a direct proof using the neighborhood definition of an open set, there's a much easier way to write it than what you've done.

Comment: @MichaelLee Can you please point out why version 1 of my proof and version 2 of my proof give different results? Which version is incorrect?

Comment: Both versions of your proof make a couple of mistakes that obscure your largest error, but it should be pretty obvious that $f(B((s, t), \frac{\varepsilon}{2}))\subseteq B(2s, \varepsilon)$, which implies that the second is correct. First, you've failed to properly define a $\delta$ relative to $\varepsilon$ (so you would have no way of knowing whether both parts give the same radius, because you haven't fixed the radius of the ball in the preimage). Also, you deduced the form of $f(B(a, \delta))$ incorrectly in the first part.

Comment: What you did in the first part is the logical equivalent of the following: $\lvert f(x)-f(x')\rvert < \varepsilon \Leftrightarrow \lvert x-x'\rvert < \delta(\varepsilon)$, so the ball around $f(x)$ of radius $\varepsilon$ is the same as the ball around $x$ of radius $\delta(\varepsilon)$. This is faulty logic, of course.